# Can someone help me in getting to know what is wrong with my Frequency multiplier circuit using 565?

Tags: integrated-circuit, proteus, pll

I just learned the working of NE565 and I tried to simulate a Frequency as multiplier using 565 in Proteus , but I don't know why PIN 4 of my NE565 is not giving any output . Its coming plane blank in output waveform in the oscilloscope . Please can someone help me in getting to know where I have gone wrong ?
I have attached my circuit diagram with my post.[image: Frequency multiplier circuit using 565]

Comment: The NE565 is a PLL IC, PLLs aren't the easiest to simulate. What I would do is first try to get the NE565 working on its own, stick to the typical application diagram as shown in the datasheet and try to get that working. I would copy this schematic and remove Q1 and U2. Connect pin 4 and 5 of the NE565 directly. If needed adjust the value of C3 and/or the reference clock frequency. When that works, add Q1 and U2 but leave pins 4 and 5 as is. Just frequency divide the signal from pin 4 and see if that works. If it does then connect pin 5 to U2 and adjust C3 and/or the reference clock frequency

Comment: I am sorry but I am still not getting anything on PIN 4. Is there any possibility that this may be due  to a bug in  NE565 module in proteus  ? Can you please recommend me any proper working circuit for 565 so that I can test it ?

Comment: Anything is possible, I didn't make the NE565 model so I don't know if/how it works. Is the VCO oscillating? If not maybe it needs a "kick" to startup. I usually use a pulsed current source for that, configure it such that it produces one current pulse shortly after the start of the simulation.

Comment: the 565 has an internal analog-multiplier as the phase-detector. Is that properly biased?